# How to allow users to register through my MVC5 .NET Webapp to azure active directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How can i have an option where users can register for an account in azure active directory if they don't already have an account using their own email? Currently i can only see an option to manually add users in through azure portal but I want to be able to allow users to register to my azure active directory programmatically through a .NET web app.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) is Microsoft’s cloud-based identity and access management service, which helps your employees sign in and access resources.

That means you need to manage the users under your organization's tenant.

All the users are employees of a company. Only in this way can users be managed easily under the same tenant.

So you need create accounts for your employees. There is not a option to make them register to Azure AD. I believe every company will provide work accounts to employees rather than asking employees to register.

If you want to work with your customers, let them register with your tenants, you should consider [Azure AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview). It provides business-to-customer identity as a service, which allows customers to register for an account in Azure AD B2C tenant.